# RabbitMQ 3.0.x issue with monitoring

Tags: monitoring, rabbitmq

I have used RabbitMQ 2.8.6 on Ubuntu 11.10 with success quite long time
and recently decided to upgrade it up to newest version (3.1.x).

I use the custom monitoring for RabbitMQ by using management plugin possibilities.
Unfortunately, on newest version this monitor didn't work by some unknown reason.
I have even tried to send simple request to check workability

```
    curl -i -u guest:guest http://127.0.0.1:55672/api/overview
```

and get strange response

```
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Server: MochiWeb/1.0 (Any of you quaids got a smint?)
    Location: http://localhost:15672/api/overview
    Date: Sat, 11 May 2013 09:37:04 GMT
    Content-Length: 0
```

instead of (as before)

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.9.0 (someone had painted it blue)
    Date: Sat, 11 May 2013 09:54:49 GMT
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 1659
    Cache-Control: no-cache

    {"management_version":"2.8.6","statistics_level":"fine",...
```

I noticed that MochiWeb server version is downgraded. Is it a RabbitMQ BUG or maybe my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Check the official docs here:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/11/19/breaking-things-with-rabbitmq-3-0/

The Management plugins now listens to 15672 and not 55672

Also, it is clear from the response that the page is permanently moved to `http://localhost:15672/api/overview`